# How to use Coalesce in MySQL

Tags: mysql, coalesce

A little help here. I really don't understand how to use this coalesce in MySQL

I have read all the pages in page 1 result of `how to use coalsece` in google result.

I know its meaning that it returns the first non-null value it encounters and null otherwise.

But it's still vague for me.

1. How come I saw queries that returns multiple values? Isn't it only the first not null value that is returned?
2. And how do it decide which column to base? `coalesce(column1,column2)`? what if first column is null and other column is not null?
3. Or if I'm wrong or my syntax is wrong, how do i properly write it?
4. Can someone provide a very good and simple example on how to use it?
5. And when it is desirable to use.

Comment: `COALESCE()` will only return a single value -- the first non-null value, as you mentioned.  If you have a specific example that defies this, please update your question.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

1. > How come i saw queries that returns multiple values? isnt it only the first not null value that is returned?

   Yes, it is only the first non-NULL value that is returned.  You must be mistaken about the queries you have seen where you thought that was not the case: if you could show us an example, we might be able to help clarify the misunderstanding.
2. > And how do it decide which column to base? coalesce(column1,column2)? what if first column is null and other column is not null?

   In order of its arguments: in this example, `column1` before `column2`.
3. > Or if im wrong or my syntax is wrong, how do i properly write it?

   You're not wrong.
4. > Can someone provide a very good and simple example on how to use it?

   Taken from [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

   > ```
   > mysql> SELECT COALESCE(NULL,1);
   >         -> 1
   > mysql> SELECT COALESCE(NULL,NULL,NULL);
   >         -> NULL
   > ```
5. > And when it is desirable to use.

   It is desirable to use whenever one wishes to select the first non-NULL value from a list.

Comment: Further to answer (5) -- also quite helpful when using LEFT JOINs.

Comment: @fenway: Depends on the logic that one is trying to implement.  Most `LEFT JOIN`s that I write don't use `COALESCE()`.

Comment: oh right, i forgot, another question. When would I want to only query the first not null in thousand of records?

Comment: @user2484763: SQL expressions, including functions like `COALESCE()`, are evaluated *for each record*; thus if records 1 and 2 have `(column1, column2)` = `(NULL, 5)` and `(10, NULL)` respectively, `COALESCE(column1, column2)` will return `5` and `10` when evaluating each record.

Answer (score 39):

I personally use coalesce when I want to find the first column that isn't blank in a row from a priority list.

Say for example I want to get a phone number from a customer table and they have 3 columns for phone numbers named mobile, home and work, but I only want to retrieve the first number that isn't blank.

In this instance, I have the priority of mobile, then home and then work.

```
TABLE STRUCTURE
--------------------------------------------
| id | customername | mobile | home | work |
--------------------------------------------
| 1  | Joe          | 123    | 456  | 789  |
--------------------------------------------
| 2  | Jane         |        | 654  | 987  |
--------------------------------------------
| 3  | John         |        |      | 321  |
--------------------------------------------

SELECT id, customername, COALESCE(mobile, home, work) AS phone FROM customers

RESULT
------------------------------
| id | customername | phone  |
------------------------------
| 1  | Joe          | 123    |
------------------------------
| 2  | Jane         | 654    |
------------------------------
| 3  | John         | 321    |
------------------------------
```

Comment: This is a really helpful explanation. I've read a lot about *how* to use it, but couldn't really parse *why* I'd use it.

Comment: Best practical example

Answer (score 3):

COALESCE will return the first non-null column or value.

Example Usage:

```
SELECT COALESCE(my_column, my_other_column, 'default') as username FROM my_table;
```

Example results:

```
my_column  my_other_column     results
null       null                'default'
null       0                   '0'
null       'jimmy'             'jimmy'
'bob'      'jimmy'             'bob'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect example of the `Coalesce` if will change the `null` fields/columns to what you want them to be in the case from `null` to `0` and `1`.

Copy this into a mysql editor it will look a lot better

```
Select "Column1 (Dont Want Touched)", 
  coalesce(column2(That you want set to 0 if null), 0) as column2 /* (give it same name as was e.g. "column2") */, 
  coalesce(column3(Instead of null set to 1) ,1) as column3 /* (give it same name as was e.g. "column3") */ 
from "MydataTable" 
Where 'somedates' in ('2015-04-10', '2015-04-03', '2015-03-27', '2015-04-17')  and id = 10 order by 'somedates';
```