# Update a specific column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

How to get updated a single column by giving the input.Here is my code.

```
$sql="UPDATE isourcetest SET hostname='".$_POST['fname']."', 
IP='".$_POST['Iname']."', location='".$_POST['Lname']."', 
network='".$_POST['nname']."', OSversion='".$_POST['oname']."', 
RAM='".$_POST['rname']."',CPUcore='".$_POST['cname']."',
CPUspeed='".$_POST['cpname']."', 
Hardwaremodel='".$_POST['hname']."'
WHERE hostname='".$_POST['fname']."'";
```

But here if i try to update a column the entire row will be updated. Please suggest a solution.I am new in sql.

Comment: See about prepared statements.

Comment: Either build the query dynamically, based upon the input. Or make sure that all the input is included (including data identical to that being updated).

Comment: ***NEVER*** put user / POST / GET data directly into a SQL query like this. Read up on `Escaping SQL inputs` and `Prepared Statements` .

Answer (score 1):

You only need to write an update of one column, for example of `hostname`:

```
$sql="UPDATE isourcetest SET hostname='".$_POST['fname']."' 
WHERE hostname='".$_POST['fname']."'";
```

Comment: Yes,but i want to update not only host name but also other fields with respect to the input giving through the portal.

Comment: Your question title does not really says that :)

Answer (score 0):

Use **[COALESCE()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104329/how-to-use-coalesce-in-mysql)**

```
$sql="UPDATE isourcetest SET hostname=COALESCE('".$_POST['fname']."', hostname), 
IP=COALESCE('".$_POST['Iname']."', IP),.....etc

WHERE hostname='".$_POST['fname']."'";
```

Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
$sql="UPDATE isourcetest SET ";
if($_POST['fname'] != '')
$sql."hostname='".$_POST['fname']."',"; 
.
.
if($_POST['hname'] != '')
$sql."Hardwaremodel='".$_POST['hname']."',";

rtrim($sql,',');

$sql."WHERE hostname='".$_POST['fname']."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me.

```
if($_POST['fname'])
{
$sql="UPDATE tablename SET hostname='".$_POST['fname']."' WHERE hostname='".$_POST['fname']."'";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$db))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

}
.
.
.
if($_POST['hname'])
{
$sql="UPDATE tablename SET Hardwaremodel='".$_POST['hname']."' WHERE hostname='".$_POST['fname']."'";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$db))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

}
```

Thank you all for the support.

Comment: Stop using MySQL_ as soon as possible and research using `MySQLi_` and or `PDO`. MySQL_ is flawed, unsafe, and Deprecated. Also do not insert POSTed or GET data directly into SQL queries as you can't trust it.