# How to create this query in MYSQL? What Join is it?

Tags: mysql, join

[i cannot create this kind of join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2dxR.png)

I have two tables on my MySQL database one is for the identity record and the another one is for , i know how to create joins like inner, left, right joins BUT i do not know how to create a join that will merge them

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the join that's different, you need to use `group by` clause and [group_concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to produce the expected results in the `record` field of the output. Whether it is a left or inner join between the 2 tables, that's for you to decide. Based on the sample data an inner join will work just fine:

```
SELECT a.id_tag, a.Name, group_concat(b.Record) as record
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.id_tag = b.id_tag
group by a.id_tag, a.Name
```

Comment: This is well explained.

Comment: does a and b means table 1 and table 2? or it is a declaration?

Comment: Yes they are shorthand table aliases

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php

```
SELECT a.id_tag, a.Name, GROUP_CONCAT(b.Record) as Records FROM tablea a LEFT JOIN tableb b ON a.id_tag = b.id_tag GROUP BY b.Record;
```

To tidy up the records and make it a bit neater you may want to look at

*COALESCE*

[How to use Coalesce in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104329/how-to-use-coalesce-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.IDtag,
       t1.Name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(t2.Record, 'no rap sheet'))
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.IDtag = t2.IDtag
GROUP BY t1.IDtag
```

Comment: I will try this one,